# Keyboard Not Working [Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS]

Tags: keyboard

I'd like some help with a recurring issue here.
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. Quite frequently, coincidentally after updating via `sudo apt update/upgrade`, my keyboard gets misconfigured and some keys stop working. For example, the <kbd>Y</kbd> key turns into the <kbd>print screen</kbd> key, and the <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>, and <kbd>Space</kbd> keys stop responding, but the others continue to work fine.

I've tried various solutions from different forums, but I can't find an effective fix. It just stops working and then, after a while, starts working again...

But this has been quite troublesome for me. I've already made sure it's not a physical keyboard issue.
Does anyone know what could be causing this and can assist me, as a huge favor?